# Fill a table from a RAND based formula in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am trying to do a Monte Carlo simulation using Excel, but a lot of the tutorials I have found are either for older versions of the product, or are not quite what I am after. A simple example of the kind of think I am after is:

Cell A1 contains the formula to simulate (for example int(6*rand())+1 to simulate rolling a dice).

I have 10 rows of "Trials". What I want is to somehow point each row at a different calculation of the formula in A1. So I would end up with something like

```
Trial   Value 
1       2
2       5
3       6
4       2
5       1
6       3
7       2
8       4
9       2
10      1
```

I have tried playing with some of the "What-if Analysis" tools, but I am a bit lost.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried copying the formula in cell `A1` (or `B2`, if we are to believe your illustration) down into the next nine cells below it?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to populate the field where I have the word "Value" with a link to the calculation, then use the "TABLE" function to fill the rows beneath it, either with a substitutable parameter or not. The placement of the cell with the initial answer is the critical step.